# jQuery Mobile partially not being applied (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

Trying to implement a simple slider menu. jQuery Mobile renders fine on the main page but on the menu div, no jQuery Mobile is being applied. Read all related examples but none of them solve the problem I'm having. Any feedback is much appreciated.

test.html.erb

```
<head>
<title>FB Style Menu</title>
<meta id="extViewportMeta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-     scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?v=31" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head> 

<div data-role="page" class="pages" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#"class="showMenu">Menu</a>
    <h1>FB Style Menu</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <p><strong>Note: You can swipe right/left to show/close menu.</strong></p>
</div>
</div>

<div id = "menu">
<h3>Menu</h3>
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="contentLink">Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" data-role = "button" class="contentLink">About </a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="contentLink">Portfolio </a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="contentLink">Contact </a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

test.js

```
$(function(){
var menuStatus;

$("a.showMenu").click(function(){
    if(menuStatus != true){
    $(".ui-page-active").animate({
        marginLeft: "250px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
      return false;
      } else {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
        marginLeft: "0px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
        return false;
      }
});

$('.pages').live("swipeleft", function(){
    if (menuStatus){
    $(".ui-page-active").animate({
        marginLeft: "0px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
      }
});

$('.pages').live("swiperight", function(){
    if (!menuStatus){
    $(".ui-page-active").animate({
        marginLeft: "165px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
      }
});

$("#menu li a").click(function(){
    var p = $(this).parent();
    if($(p).hasClass('active')){
        $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
        $(p).addClass('active');
    }
});

});
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>fuseGap</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript">if (window.location.hash == '#_=_')window.location.hash = '';</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="arc2theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to place the var p inside the jQuery selector syntax.

p.hasClass(....

Should be good enough.

regarding the mobile, I believe jQuery mobile looks for divs with data-role  = page, your menu div is outside of that.

Try adding data-role = page to your menu div .